# Onclick of recyclerview nothing happens

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

Adapter of RecyclerView

```
public class SongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList;

    public SongsAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList,Context context) {
        this.songList = songList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view,context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(songList.get(position).get("file_name"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context){
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitemtextview);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/tan_background"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/listitemtextview"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

On click of recyclerview is not working.I want to move to next activity on click of recyclerview. Please help.I tried doing everything but nothing works.I went through stackoverflow's all question related to the same topic.I dont have any onclick=true in my CardView layout

Comment: my guess is that you are missing itemView.setOnClickListener(this) in MyViewHolder's constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `itemView.setOnClickListner(this)` inside `public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context)`

Answer (score 0):

As per android click listener you need to register first with listener and then after you can get event in onClick() so first register listener with clickeble object and then after you can get event in onClick() or Otherwise you can directly register using anonymous class like following way

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

or

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```